# How to render a page based on the button clicked on another page django

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, render

I have a **page** like that

```
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img alt="" class="thumbnail" src="{{ product.images.all.0.image.url }}">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h5><strong>{{ product.name }}</strong></h5>
                <hr>
                <button data-product="{{ product.id }}" data-action="add"
                        class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>

                <a data-product="{{ product.id }}" data-action="Save" class="btn btn-outline-secondary detail"
                   href="{% url 'detail' %}"> Detail</a>
                .....
```

and when the user click on Detail, it should go to another page to display the details of the product based on which detail button he clicked on so I made **detail.js** file like that

```
var detailBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("detail") //get all add to cart button with class update-cart

for (i = 0; i < detailBtns.length; i++) {
    detailBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId )
        console.log(current_user)
        GetDetail(productId, action) // this function will be called and will pass product id and action in body to your view for further processing.
    })
}

function GetDetail(productId, action){
console.log("func")
    var url = '/detail/'

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({"productId": productId, "action": action})
    })
    .then((response) =>{
        return response.json()
    })

    .then((data) =>{
        console.log('data:',data)
        location.reload()
    })

}
```

and in the **views** there's a function that is connected to the URL detail/

```
def detail(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    context = {
        'product':product
    }
    print(productId)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

but there is an error when I click on detail of any product **"JSONDecodeError. Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"**

Comment: Can you share what `request.body` has?

Answer (score 0):

[Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) would make your life so much simpler. You could achieve the same functionality with a few lines of code. Generic views take very common tasks like "showing all the items from a model" or "showing the details of a specific model instance" (the two things you're doing here) and abstract away most of the tedious implementation details. Use them if your app is simple

this will make your life a lot easier:

#### use a [List View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) from your first page's view

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class ProductListView(ListView):
  model = Product
  context_object_name = "products"
  template_name = "yourListTemplate.html"
```

you can keep your template the same since the context object name was changed to products

#### use a [Detail View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) to create product detail pages for each product

essentially you only have to tell the view which model to use, and pass the model instance's id as a url param and it will give you access to that instance in the template

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Product
  context_object_name = "product"
  template_name = "yourDetailTemplate.html"
```

#### and in your urls.py

```
from .views import ProductListView, ProductDetailView

urlpatterns = [
  #...
  path("listViewEndpoint/", ProductListView.as_view(), name="productList"),
  path("detailViewEndpoing/<int:pk>/", ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="productDetail"),
]
```

#### and in yourListTemplate.html

change that a tag to this

```
<a href="{% url 'productDetail' product.pk %}">Detail</a>
```